# Unpixelated Screenshot images

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign

I have some work to showcase: images which are screenshots of work which are online. However when arranging these screenshot images in Illustrator, Photoshop and InDesign, they all appear to be pixelated. I do not have the raw images because it is work which is made online. Is there anyway I can use these screenshots to not be pixelated?

Answer (score 2):

If you have screenshot software such as SnagIt for Windows or SnapzPro for the MacOS you can set the screenshot to be enlarged.

I customarily take screenshots at 400%.

You can then place the screenshots into Indesign, or Illustrator, and reduce the images there. This essentially increases the pixel density of the images.

If using Photoshop you can easily resize the image with Resample *unchecked* and get a higher PPI image which appear much cleaner when printing. If you do need to resample the image, using the Nearest Neighbor resampling method often result in the best quality.

Comment: For clarity: the 400% enlargement that SnagIt creates is a resampled image, correct? Do you know what method is used? Bicubic etc?

Comment: I'm not 100% certain how the screencap software creates the enlargement. But I can tell you at 400% it's crystal clear on the Mac with SnapzPro. So any unresampled reduction is fine. I would guess they sue Nearest Neighbor.

Answer (score 1):

In Photoshop, scaling in multiple of 25% offers better quality (at 25%, 50%, 75%).

InDesign handles images different than Photoshop, so make sure that images are set to 100% quality when in edit and preview mode.

Comment: I need to scale the images down to fit on the Artboards in indesign, however when this is done the images at first seem to be clear. however when i rescale them automatically they all become pixelated. Do you know if there is a way of this not happening

Answer (score 0):

If the work you are showcasing is a web site, a screen shot is perfectly acceptable. Yes, it will be pixelated. This is expected and no one would expect otherwise.